# how to put dash button on dockbarx

Tags: unity, uninstall, dockbarx

Im new in Ubuntu so I need help from pros

**I like the dash feature but i don't like the unity launcher how can i make a dash button on "DOCKBARX"**

ADDITION:
how to remove the unity launcher

Comment: Install awn (Avant Window Navigator) and customize it

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it at least at this moment ,but you can change the position of the unity launcher to the bottom using a compiz plugin
See [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/how-to-move-unity-launcher-to-bottom-of.html) guide for it